# Microsoft Access Checkboxes are behaving like radio buttons

Tags: forms, ms-access, checkbox, radio-button

I have a form in MS Access that I am developing. I have two checkboxes that are not mutually exclusive - CANCELLED and SUBMITTED.  The checkboxes are not bound to any data table or query.  I want the checkboxes to behave like you would expect checkboxes to behave - I can select them independently - zero, one or two of the controls can be checked.  Very oddly though, they are behaving as if they were grouped radio buttons - if I choose one checkbox the other is unchecked. Like a radio button, I can't unselect it at all. This all seems related to the OptionValue property. I tried unsetting the value, but Access won't allow that and gives an error! I have also tried setting them to different values including 0 or -1 hoping that was a magic value to indicate that my checkbox should behave like a checkbox. How do I get checkboxes to behave like checkboxes?

[Access checkbox property editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmHLm.png)

Checkboxes should not be mutually exclusive options

Comment: A checkbox not in an Option frame does not have OptionValue property. It will have ControlSource. Your checkboxes must be inside an Option frame to present this property and cause this behavior.

Comment: "June 7's" comment above was the problem in my case!  I had added an Option Frame just as a visual grouping mechanism without any intent for it to affect the behavior of checkboxes that were inside of it - but that is exactly what happened.

Comment: Use a Rectangle control instead of Frame.